# Vrms, RF power and PAPR of Random bit string Votlage signal

Tags: rms, power

I have a random bit string which is being generated by an arbitrary waveform generator (AWG), being amplified by an RF amplifier to drive an optical phase modulator for binary phase shift keying modulation modulation.

The RF amplifier has a saturation power, and I want to know if my signal is going to cause the amplifier to saturate.

To do this I understand that I need to calculate the Vrms of my digital bit string (AC coupled so centered around 0) coming out of my AWG, use that with the impedance of the transmission line (50ohm) to calculate the [RF power.](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/measurement-control-rf-power-parti.html) One can then also create a normalised [Complementary Cumulative Distribution Function][2] (CCDF) to calculate the PARP to calculate whether the amplifier will saturate.

Problem is a random bit string is random. I know PRBS sequences are used in systems to test systems, but I can't seem to find an expression for the RMS of PRBS, between 0 1, let alone -1 and 1.

Would it be valid to approximate my data with a square wave?

If not, my data block transmissions are 10^6 in length. Log2(10^6)=~20. Is calculating the RMS of for PRBS20 sufficiently represenative of my signal?

[2]: [https://www.keysight.com/blogs/tech/rfmw/2018/11/29/an-essential-step-to-generate-a-modulation-signal-ccdf#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20CCDF,-cosine](https://www.keysight.com/blogs/tech/rfmw/2018/11/29/an-essential-step-to-generate-a-modulation-signal-ccdf#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20CCDF,-cosine))%20baseband%20filter%20waveform

Answer (score 1):

A peak to average is determined, accurately with a CCDF function, for cases when we want to operate at a specific level at the input of the amplifier relative to the waveform's peak to average ratio, but in general cases we can also simply use the "input one dB compression (input P1dB)" and "input third order intercept" specifications for the amplifier to get an approximate consideration of the amount of distortion introduced due to non-linearities. This latter case is very straight forward and often sufficient to back-off from the input P1dB based on the peak-avg ratio.

For a PBRS waveform, if the waveform is indeed a square-wave (and the amplifier's bandwidth is sufficient to maintain that: I recommend the high frequency range of the amplifier to be at least 10x the PBRS rate, and the low frequency range to be the PBRS repetition rate), then the peak-average ratio of the PBRS waveform will be 0 dB, and you can run the waveform into saturation with no consequence. It's only the cases when the waveform is filtered (as is often done when spectral occupancy is a concern since an unfiltered PBRS waveform will take up significantly more bandwidth) that a peak to average ratio will develop, and the PA saturation will "undo" that filtering leading to spectral regrowth and other distortion products.  Other distortions could result due to the amplifier used regardless if the amplifier does not have flat gain and linear phase over the bandwidth of the waveform (or any of the other components such as the optical phase modulator). If the resulting optical spectrum is observable and that spectrum is a Sinc function (Sinc squared as a power spectrum), then the waveform is a square wave.

As for computing the average power in a 50 ohm system, we can also do this on an oscilloscope measurement of the arb output terminated in 50 ohms (or simulation of the waveform matched to the peak voltage of the square wave pattern out of the arb when terminated in 50 ohms), by computing the rms value of the waveform, which assuming the waveform has no DC component would be equal to the standard deviation $\sigma_x$ in volts. For an actual square wave the measurement is trivial since the standard deviation for a square wave is the peak voltage! The power in dBm is then given as:

$$PdBm = 10log(20\sigma_x^2)$$

Or more generally for any load $R$:

$$PdBm = 10log(1000\sigma_x^2/R)$$

(Power in Watts is $v^2/R$ where $R=50$, so in mW is $1000(v^2/50) = 20v^2$, and then converted to dB to get in units of dBm or dB relative to 1 mW).  For instance, if the standard deviation of the waveform with no DC component is 0.707 volts across 50 ohms (or the rms value with a DC component), then the power dissipated is 10 dBm.

The duration for the measurement of standard deviation (for cases when it is not a square wave and trivially the peak voltage) is any duration sufficient that the DC component is sufficiently close to zero, when the waveform itself is indeed zero mean. If we arbitrarily truncate the PBRS waveform, there will likely be a residual average (DC component), and the longer we make the duration, the smaller that average will be.

Comment: After I posted my question, I realised that for ideal square pulses in a PRBS, cantered around 0V the Vrms would by the same as a for a square wave, due to “squaring” part of RM”S” of the signal. It doesn’t matter how many 0s or 1s you have in your bit string, as when you square the negative voltage or the positive voltage either of them, you get the same value. It's then trivial that your power is constant and the PARP is 0dB and you can run your amp into saturation. That being said I am still somewhat confused.

Comment: Thinking about the spectral content a pure square wave, each harmonic has a different amplitude. You could envisage a situation where your fundamental harmonic has a high enough amplitude to saturate while the others don’t? This could then occur even with a square wave and distort your waveform? This interpretation comes from my (perhaps wrong) interpretation that saturation is an effect of a voltage signal being clipped by a limited supply rail?

Comment: However, if you can amplifier a true square wave in a saturated regime without distorting it, the saturation must therefore be an effect which occurs across the entire operating bandwidth of the signal. If the entire signal has enough power to saturate the amplifier, the gain of amplifier reduces across the entire operating bandwidth, not just for the peak frequencies, is this correct?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply though. I think I need to read more about IP3 points, as I’m not very familiar with them. I have measured the saturation, vs input power roll off of my amplifier with a Vector network analyser to find the P1dB and P3dB compression points.

Comment: Nice observations. For a square wave the fundamental component is larger than the peak value (by $4/\pi$), but consider that the square wave is the sum of the odd harmonics, so at the points where the fundamental would clip, some of the other components would clip as well and it ends up reducing them all consistent with your third point: saturation does decrease the gain of the amplifier consistently across frequency.